# manufactured conflicts – avocado-obsessed, narcissistic millennials

Tags: phrase-meaning

> TOO often discussion of generations descends into stereotypes and **manufactured conflicts – avocado-obsessed, narcissistic millennials** against selfish, wasteful baby boomers. Instead of serious analysis, we get apocryphal predictions about millennials “killing” everything from wine corks to the napkin industry.

Source: [NewScientist](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg25133524-300-generation-covid-what-the-pandemic-means-for-young-peoples-futures/)

I have no idea of what "conflicts – avocado-obsessed' means. Avocado the fruit is also called alligator avocado, and if we associated it with "conflicts", it seems to imply to the people who are combative... I am not sure. What does it mean actually?

Comment: There's a cultural association between the millennial generation and a love of avocados.

Comment: I'm quite old, and I love avocados. They are really good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *manufactured conflicts* refers forward to a conflict between two different generations of human beings, which we can call A against B:

A is *avocado-obsessed, narcissistic millennials*

and

B is *selfish, wasteful baby boomers*.

Group A is concerned with health foods, symbolized by "avocado-obsessed".

Both A and B are examples of *stereotypes*, which are simplistic assumptions about groups of people.

Comment: You might add 'stereotype' to your answer, as this word directly applies to the question. As in "the stereotype of Millennials is that of avocado eating narcissists' and 'the the stereotype of Baby-Boomers is that of being selfish and wasteful', showing more clearly that 'avocados' are an example of one of the stereotypes in the example text.

Comment: @MarkRipley  Noted.